# Why won't array[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() pass on to array[i][0]

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to make a javascript program that takes a string and capitalizes the first letter of every word and makes every other character lowercase.

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  var array = str.split(" ");
  for(var i =0; i< array.length ; i++){
    array[i][0] = array[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase();

  } 
  var finalString = array.join(" ")
  return finalString ; 
}

console.log(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

For some reason `array[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase();` won't pass it's value to `array[i][0]`. This ends up making it return the string with just all lowercase letters instead of having the first letter of each word being capitalized.

Comment: You can't index into the string like that with `array[i][0]`

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like you want to do something more like this:

```
function titleCase(str) {
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  var array = str.split(" ");
  for(var i =0; i< array.length ; i++){
    //array[i] is an immutable string. So we need to rebuild it instead.
    array[i] = array[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + array[i].substring(1);
  } 
  var finalString = array.join(" ")
  return finalString; 
}

titleCase("I'm a little tea pot");
```

Strings *can* be read as char arrays using bracket notation. However, you cannot change a particular character that way since strings are not mutable objects.

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript strings are immutable, so you cannot actually change individual characters by indexing them using the `[]` operator. Here is a fixed version that uses `substring` to build the final string instead:

**Live Demo:**

```js
function titleCase(str) {
  str = str.toLowerCase();
  var array = str.split(" ");
  for(var i =0; i< array.length ; i++){
    array[i] = array[i].charAt(0).toUpperCase() + array[i].substring(1);

  } 
   var finalString = array.join(" ")
  return finalString ; 
}

alert(titleCase("I'm a little tea pot"));
```

JSFiddle Version: https://jsfiddle.net/rakdtpbb/

Answer (score 0):

The `toUpperCase()` method returns the value of the string converted to uppercase, but does not affect the value of the string itself.

Comment: Thanks that solved my problem. I did not realize you cannot index individual characters.